# SQLite query with multiple joins

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

This is pretty much just a simple join statemnet I believe. I've not worked with SQL much lately and seem to have forgotten how to do this. What I have is an item with few columns in it that reference another table for the name of that field. Like this:

```
id, name, effect1, effect2, effect3, effect4
```

The effects reference another table that only has `a`, `id`, and `name` columns. What I'm trying to do is run a query that will pull those names for each of those effects.

Something like:

```
SELECT i.name,e.name AS effect1, e.name AS effect2, e.name AS effect3, 
       e.name AS effect4 
FROM item i, effects e 
WHERE i.effect1 = e.name 
 AND i.effect2 = e.name 
 AND i.effect3 = e.name 
 AND i.effect4 = e.name
```

So, say I have an item that has values like this:

```
Toast, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

and the effects are:

```
1, burned
2, untoasted
3, wet
4, texas
```

I want it to display `toast, burned, untoasted, wet, texas`

And ideas?

update:

```
Table items
id, name, weight, value, effect1,effect2,effect3,effect4

Table effects
id, name
```

In the effect1,... columns are the id number for the corresponding item in the effect table. A lot ofitems are going to share the same effects, so instead of inflating this already large database with redundant data, I decided to use a join to save space. At the same time I managed how to forget to do it, lol

Update #2 
This is the effect I'm going for, but on more than one of the effect columns

```
SELECT i.name, i.weight,i.value, e.name AS 'effect 1' 
FROM ingredients i JOIN effects e ON effects._id=i.effect1
```

This works for 1, but if I try to do multiple it just crashes. Any ideas how I can get that effect for all 4 effects?

Comment: What do the tables look like? This seems like a very odd table design.  I would expect there to be a Item ItemEffects and Effect table.  but this situation only has two and you're wanting to get the values for the relative fields... Can you post the table structures  what are the fields of Item and Effects table?

Comment: something like this, but can do all the effects

Comment: Thats weird, SO is crashing when I try to paste from my clipboard now... heres the query that worked for one of the effects SELECT i.name, i.weight,i.value, e.name AS 'effect' FROM ingredients i JOIN effects e ON effects._id=i.effect1

Comment: If you're looking to save space, then @xQbert is right, you're missing the items_effects join table, something like: 

    `create table items_effects ( 
      item_id integer not null, 
      effect_id integer not null,
      place integer not null,
      primary key (item_id, effect_id)
    );`

Comment: and just to clarify, you ask "I want it to display toast, burned, untoasted, wet, texas" - is that really what you want or is it just the data, and what are you using to display it? (sqlite's commandline client or something else?)

Comment: Im actually writting a program for android for a client. Since every item has 4 effects, then I dont need to worry about another table since its a fixed amount. If there were varying amounts of effects per item, then I would change it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need a distinct join for every column:

```
SELECT i.name
     , i.weight
     , i.value
     , e1.name AS effect1
     , e2.name AS effect2
     , e3.name AS effect3
     , e4.name AS effect4
FROM   ingredients i 
LEFT   JOIN effects e1 ON e1.id = i.effect1
LEFT   JOIN effects e2 ON e2.id = i.effect2
LEFT   JOIN effects e3 ON e3.id = i.effect3
LEFT   JOIN effects e4 ON e4.id = i.effect4;
```

`LEFT JOIN` still keeps the ingredient if any of the effects is missing.
The query depends on `effects.id` being *unique*.

You can achieve the same with correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT i.name
     , i.weight
     , i.value
     , (SELECT e.name FROM effects e WHERE e.id = i.effect1) AS effect1
     , (SELECT e.name FROM effects e WHERE e.id = i.effect2) AS effect2
     , (SELECT e.name FROM effects e WHERE e.id = i.effect3) AS effect3
     , (SELECT e.name FROM effects e WHERE e.id = i.effect4) AS effect4
FROM   ingredients i;
```

#### Database design

If every `ingredient` has 4 `effects` your db design is fine. If the number of effects vary or you have additional information per effect, you might consider an `n:m` relationship between `ingredients` and `effects`, implemented by an additional table. (Replacing the four effect* columns.) Could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ingredients_effects (
  ingredients_id integer REFERENCES ingredients(id)
, effects_id     integer REFERENCES effects(id)
  -- additional data like quantity or notes?
, PRIMARY KEY (ingredients_id, effects_id)
);
```

[More details in the fine manual.](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

Comment: Erwin has it, gotta say though, strange db design.

Comment: the number of effects doesnt apply. I created an app a while ago where there were varying questions in categories, and you never knew how many times that question was going to be used, so I set up a relational table to do that. But, since this is fixed I dont see a point in another table.

Comment: I've spent days trying to do something similar. The first option with multiple joins just kept returning absolute rubbish, but your second suggestion worked like a charm! For some reason SQLite can't handle counts on many joins...